# Creating a new column to identify if two columns are identical but have distinct value in the third column

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to my data frame with true and false values to tell me if two columns have duplicated values but the third column has a distinct value.

This is the table I have now:

```
| ID  | name | age|student|
| --- | -----|----|-------|
| 1   | Joe  |23  | Yes   |
| 2   | Rayan|13  | Yes   |
| 3   | Sara |20  | No    |
| 4   | Rayan|21  | Yes   |
| 5   | Sara |20  | Yes   |
| 6   | Joe  |23  | Yes   |
```

I want to check if name and age have duplicated values but student has different value. I want the resulted column to look like this:

```
| ID  | name | age|student|satisfy|
| --- | -----|----|-------|-------|
| 1   | Joe  |23  | Yes   | False |
| 2   | Rayan|13  | Yes   | False |
| 3   | Sara |20  | No    | False |
| 4   | Rayan|21  | Yes   | False |
| 5   | Sara |20  | Yes   | True  |
| 6   | Joe  |23  | Yes   | False |
```

Only Sara satisfies the condition because in age and name have duplicated values but student has different values. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this would help you:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:6),
  name = c("Joe", "Rayan", "Sara", "Rayan", "Sara", "Joe"),
  age = c(23, 13, 20, 21, 20, 23),
  student = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
)

(df$satisfy <- duplicated(df[,2:3]) & !(duplicated(df[,2:4])))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The first conditions `duplicated(df[,2:3])` checks returns `TRUE` if name and age is duplicated .

The second conditions `duplicated(df[,2:4]` returns `TRUE` if name and age and student is duplicated but then negates `!`.

Combined it should give you the column result you want.

Cheers
Hannes

Comment: This is a simple and accurate answer. I tried to set from_last to TRUE so I get TRUE for both Sara's entries but I couldn't. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If name is good enough then I would follow up with `(df$satisfyAll <- df$name %in% df$name[df$satisfy])`. If name is not good enough, I would generate a helper column eg. `name_age` and use this one for the follow up. 

But probably in this case and if dplyr is ok then I would go with an answer like @akrun, ```df %>% 
  group_by(name, age) %>% 
  mutate(
    satisfy = ifelse(n_distinct(student)==2, TRUE, FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()```

Comment: Why do we need the follow up?

Comment: Both conditions only returns logical vectors and do not know which rows belongs together. You could pipe into the follow up or do something with match to extract the names of the duplicated, but why try to do everything in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(name, age) %>% 
    mutate(ind =  n_distinct(student) > 1, 
    student = ind & duplicated(ind), ind = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#     id name    age student
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>  
#1     1 Joe      23 FALSE  
#2     2 Rayan    13 FALSE  
#3     3 Sara     20 FALSE  
#4     4 Rayan    21 FALSE  
#5     5 Sara     20 TRUE   
#6     6 Joe      23 FALSE
```

Comment: This does not work if I have more than two entries. For example, once I add another row that has Sara with age of 20, it results in another true. I only want to get one of them.